# Determining $\mu$-invariant of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

From Pollack's table on his homepage, I have the values of mu invariant of elliptic curves 38B1 & 38B2 (labeled as in Cremona table). But I need to know the values of mu invariants of 38A1, 38A2, 38A3. Also please inform me, how to calculate the mu invariants of elliptic curves in general.

Comment: To be precise, the webpage http://math.bu.edu/people/rpollack/Data/curves1-5000 gives you the $\mu$-invariant for the primes 2,3,5,7,11, and 13 for 38a1 and 38b1 (and many other $X_0$-optimal curves).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At what prime ? Well, let $p$ be an odd prime at which $E$ has good ordinary reduction. There are two ways:

- Use sage or magma to compute the analytic $p$-adic L-function via modular symbols. In sage this is E.padic_lseries(p).series(n) where $n$ is the precision to which the series is computed. The $\mu$-invariant is often easy to read off the first few terms with a small $n$. That is what Robert Pollack did.
- Assume the conjecture by Greenberg that the $\mu$-invariant is zero for the minimal curve. Then you know immediately that the $\mu$-invariant is zero for all such primes $p$ except the ones for which $E$ has an isogeny of that degree. Once you know the $\mu$-invariant for the minimal curve it is easy to compute it for all others as it just changes with the quotient of the periods.

For the isogeny class 38a, the $\mu$-invariant should be trivial for all good ordinary primes $p>3$. For $p=3$, it is $\mu=0$ for 38a3, $\mu=1$ for 38a1 and $\mu=2$ for 38a2.

Comment: Kindly explain 'n' in "n is the precision to which the series is computed".

Comment: The higher $n$, the higher the precision of each coefficient of the series. See the section 3 of http://wstein.org/papers/shark/ for the detailed definition of $n$. Sage computes $P_n(T)$ in the notations of this paper.